# Signature verification fails for secure boot kernel

Tags: linux, grub, kernel, secure-boot

I'm trying to setup secure boot with using custom keys exclusively following the [guide from rodsbooks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html). I created and enrolled keys for db, KEK and PK and signed grub and the kernel image accordingly (with the same db key) and could verify the signature with `sbverify` against the created db key.

If I turn on Secure Boot it fails to verify the signature for the kernel image:

**"/boot/vmlinuz... has invalid signature"**

What I figured out so far:

- The signature for grub is working. If I remove it, I'll get a different error (the red box)
- using different keys for grub and kernel image has the same result (I would also expect that it's ok to use the same key)
- Signing the kernel with `sbsign` or `osslsigncode` (like [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1560481/how-to-secure-boot-efi-images-signed-with-an-installed-custom-key)) makes no difference, same result
- `bootctl` status only shows grub as bootloader
- I did not change the name of the kernel image. I would expect there is not change in grub necessary
- MokManager (i.e. mmx64.efi) is present (but shouldn't make a difference here?)

Kernel is version 4.19.0-6; Distribution is Debian 10, if that matters.

Comment: Are you able to start the kernel image directly from EFI? (For example, by adding it as a bootloader via efibootmgr, or by starting it from EFI Shell?)

Comment: How does that make a difference?

Comment: I don't know Debian, but is it possible that you're signing a different `vmlinuz...` than `grub` is trying to boot? Is `/boot/vmlinuz` a symlink to somewhere else, as a part of package management for instance?